# php set_include_path function confusion?

Tags: php

i have already searched internet and (php mannual too a little hard to understand) but didn't get satisfied about php's `set_include_path`, i know 
that its used to set the include path for the running script,but i dont quit understand what does `PATH_SEPARATOR` constant do in php `set_include_path` function.

so for example

```
set_include_path('./php-include'.PATH_SEPARATOR.'./functions');
```

i don't quiet get it please some one explain it thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATH_SEPARATOR is the character that's used to separate multiple paths in a string, such as the include_path.

On Unix, PATH_SEPARATOR is ':' while on Windows it's ';'

Answer (score 1):

PHP's include path can have multiple directories, that are searched in order for the file you are trying to include. The way that was chosen to list many directories is to separate the directories with a character that they know will never appear in a directory's name.

For instance, on Windows, `;` is such character. So, when PHP needs to find a file, it can simply split the string representing the various include paths on each occurrence of the `;` character and search for the file in each of the directories.